# Stopping a Handler Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

On one of our applications, we use a background service with a notification (basically a foreground service but you get the idea, activity is closeable while the service stays alive.)

On this service, we use 3 separate `HandlerThreads` with `Handlers` to manage various operations with some delay (for example, 250 milliseconds). Now, these actions need to be stopped if the screen goes off and be resumed if the screen goes back on, due to this situation we added a broadcast receiver to the service, and created-deleted threads. Everything works fine so far.

In order to stop the operations, we deleted the messages on handlers by calling `Handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` and it actually clears the message queue. **However, the handler thread stays alive.** And this is a problem.

In order to stop the thread we used `HandlerThread.quit()` which internally calls `Looper.quit()` that we thought, that it will finish the thread, but no sir, it does not delete the thread because we get some reports from Fabric that goes `pthread_create failed (1040kb stack), try again` or something. Under it, **there were 940 separate threads that named the same, which caused a OOM (Out Of Memory) error.** This was a huge mistake from us.

The question: How can we stop the handler threads? Is `HandlerThread.interrupt()` will be enough? Any help is appreciated, thanks. PS: I cannot share any source codes, and in this situation I don't think it is necessary since the question itself is self-explanatory.

Edit: Since you asked for some code, I'm showing an example of some logic I'm following.

```
public class ThreadHelper implements Runnable
{

    private HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("ThreadName");
    private Handler handler;

    private boolean shouldRun = true;

    public ThreadHelper()
    {
        handlerThread.start();
        startThread();
    }

    // Called if the screen state is turned on.
    public void startThread()
    {
        if (handlerThread == null)
        {
             handlerThread = new HandlerThread("ThreadName");
             handlerThread.start();
        }
        if (handler == null)
        {
             handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
             handler.post(this);
        }
    }

    // Called if the screen state is turned off.
    public void stopThread()
    {
        shouldRun = false;
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        handlerThread.quit();
        try
        {
            handlerThread.interrupt();
        }
        catch (Exception ignored)
        {
            // Skipped Thread.currentThread().interrupt() check here since this is
            // called from a different thread that is not associated.
        }

        // remove variables.
        handler = null;
        handlerThread = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (shouldRun)
        {
            // rest of the code without having a long-running
            // operation. Mostly ends in 1~2 millseconds.

            // Continue looping.
            handler.postDelayed(this, 250); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: plz show us some code ,if you still have a long running task that is still running in the thread => calling quit and interrupt will not stop it

Comment: unless you add an if condition to check for interruption in the thread to stop it

Comment: Added some example code.